# How to convert binary message into string

Tags: string, matlab, binary, ascii

i have a binary stream,

```
message_1 = '0100100001000101010011000100110001001111'
```

Now i want to convert this binary stream into its equivalent characters i.e. the result should be 'HELLO'. Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this -

```
char(bin2dec(reshape(message_1,8,[])'))'
```

Comment: haha this time I had to ditch bsxfun :) thanks! +1 you too for keeping faith on bsxfun!

Answer (score 2):

Convert from characters to numbers (`-'0'`); arrange the bits in groups of 8 (`reshape`); convert each group into a number between 0 and 255 (`sum(bsxfun(@times, ...))`); and from that to `char`:

```
>> char(sum(bsxfun(@times, reshape(message_1-'0',8,[]), 2.^(7:-1:0).')))
ans =
HELLO
```